# Kernel panic on Lenovo ThinkPad W510 Ubuntu 10.10

Tags: kernel, capslock, dmesg

When I leave my Lenovo ThinkPad W510 laptop unattended it locks the screen as it is supposed to do. But when I come back I usually find the kernel panic going on on the laptop: the Caps Lock light is blinking and it prevents me from unlocking the screen, because I have keyboard layout switch assigned to Caps Lock.

If I eventually manage to unlock the screen and log in, the Caps Lock light stops blinking in a few minutes.

Here is a part of `dmesg`:

```
[    1.877333] usb 1-1.3: new full speed USB device using ehci_hcd and address 3
[    1.957100] firewire_core: created device fw0: GUID f0def1ff0037d4ff, S400
[    2.079469] usb 1-1.4: new full speed USB device using ehci_hcd and address 4
[    2.091158]  sda1 sda2 sda3 sda4 < sda5 sda6 sda7 >
[        2.123535] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Attached SCSI disk
[    2.286641] usb 1-1.6: new high speed USB device using ehci_hcd and address 5
[    2.525977] ata2: SATA link up 1.5 Gbps (SStatus 113 SControl 300)
[    2.529184] ata2.00: ACPI cmd e3/00:1f:00:00:00:a0 (IDLE) succeeded
[    2.529752] ata2.00: ACPI cmd e3/00:02:00:00:00:a0 (IDLE) succeeded
[    2.531511] ata2.00: ATAPI: Optiarc DVD RW AD-7700H, 1.FA, max UDMA/100
[    2.535236] ata2.00: ACPI cmd e3/00:1f:00:00:00:a0 (IDLE) succeeded
[    2.536525] ata2.00: ACPI cmd e3/00:02:00:00:00:a0 (IDLE) succeeded
[    2.538338] ata2.00: configured for UDMA/100
[    2.557568] scsi 1:0:0:0: CD-ROM            Optiarc  DVD RW AD-7700H  1.FA PQ: 0 ANSI: 5
[    2.559714] sr0: scsi3-mmc drive: 62x/62x writer dvd-ram cd/rw xa/form2 cdda tray
[    2.559720] Uniform CD-ROM driver Revision: 3.20
[    2.559888] sr 1:0:0:0: Attached scsi CD-ROM sr0
[    2.559940] sr 1:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg1 type 5
[    2.905267] ata5: SATA link down (SStatus 0 SControl 300)
[    3.274577] ata6: SATA link down (SStatus 0 SControl 300)
[    4.724933] EXT4-fs (sda5): INFO: recovery required on readonly filesystem
[    4.724937] EXT4-fs (sda5): write access will be enabled during recovery
[    6.659250] EXT4-fs (sda5): orphan cleanup on readonly fs
[    6.659258] EXT4-fs (sda5): ext4_orphan_cleanup: deleting unreferenced inode 1059084
[    6.659308] EXT4-fs (sda5): ext4_orphan_cleanup: deleting unreferenced inode 1059081
[    6.659325] EXT4-fs (sda5): ext4_orphan_cleanup: deleting unreferenced inode 1059045
[    6.659334] EXT4-fs (sda5): ext4_orphan_cleanup: deleting unreferenced inode 1059044
[    6.659343] EXT4-fs (sda5): ext4_orphan_cleanup: deleting unreferenced inode 262692
[    6.659353] EXT4-fs (sda5): ext4_orphan_cleanup: deleting unreferenced inode 1059043
[    6.659362] EXT4-fs (sda5): ext4_orphan_cleanup: deleting unreferenced inode 1059042
[    6.659370] EXT4-fs (sda5): ext4_orphan_cleanup: deleting unreferenced inode 1059040
[    6.659379] EXT4-fs (sda5): ext4_orphan_cleanup: deleting unreferenced inode 1059034
[    6.659387] EXT4-fs (sda5): ext4_orphan_cleanup: deleting unreferenced inode 1059032
[    6.659396] EXT4-fs (sda5): ext4_orphan_cleanup: deleting unreferenced inode 1059036
[    6.659412] EXT4-fs (sda5): ext4_orphan_cleanup: deleting unreferenced inode 1058998
[    6.659422] EXT4-fs (sda5): ext4_orphan_cleanup: deleting unreferenced inode 1058984
[    6.659430] EXT4-fs (sda5): ext4_orphan_cleanup: deleting unreferenced inode 262690
[    6.659440] EXT4-fs (sda5): ext4_orphan_cleanup: deleting unreferenced inode 262689
[    6.659453] EXT4-fs (sda5): ext4_orphan_cleanup: deleting unreferenced inode 262688
[    6.659463] EXT4-fs (sda5): ext4_orphan_cleanup: deleting unreferenced inode 262687
[    6.659475] EXT4-fs (sda5): ext4_orphan_cleanup: deleting unreferenced inode 262686
[    6.659483] EXT4-fs (sda5): ext4_orphan_cleanup: deleting unreferenced inode 262356
[    6.659492] EXT4-fs (sda5): ext4_orphan_cleanup: deleting unreferenced inode 1058981
[    6.659501] EXT4-fs (sda5): ext4_orphan_cleanup: deleting unreferenced inode 1057421
[    6.659516] EXT4-fs (sda5): ext4_orphan_cleanup: deleting unreferenced inode 1059004
[    6.659532] EXT4-fs (sda5): ext4_orphan_cleanup: deleting unreferenced inode 1058882
[    6.659553] EXT4-fs (sda5): ext4_orphan_cleanup: deleting unreferenced inode 1058881
[    6.659571] EXT4-fs (sda5): ext4_orphan_cleanup: deleting unreferenced inode 131135
[    6.659586] EXT4-fs (sda5): ext4_orphan_cleanup: deleting unreferenced inode 1322297
[    6.659612] EXT4-fs (sda5): ext4_orphan_cleanup: deleting unreferenced inode 1058909
[    6.659622] EXT4-fs (sda5): ext4_orphan_cleanup: deleting unreferenced inode 1058908
[    6.659631] EXT4-fs (sda5): ext4_orphan_cleanup: deleting unreferenced inode 135898
[    6.659641] EXT4-fs (sda5): ext4_orphan_cleanup: deleting unreferenced inode 135897
[    6.659650] EXT4-fs (sda5): ext4_orphan_cleanup: deleting unreferenced inode 135896
[    6.659658] EXT4-fs (sda5): ext4_orphan_cleanup: deleting unreferenced inode 135888
[    6.659668] EXT4-fs (sda5): ext4_orphan_cleanup: deleting unreferenced inode 135690
[    6.659677] EXT4-fs (sda5): ext4_orphan_cleanup: deleting unreferenced inode 135109
[    6.659685] EXT4-fs (sda5): ext4_orphan_cleanup: deleting unreferenced inode 135108
[    6.659693] EXT4-fs (sda5): ext4_orphan_cleanup: deleting unreferenced inode 135106
[    6.659702] EXT4-fs (sda5): ext4_orphan_cleanup: deleting unreferenced inode 131136
[    6.659709] EXT4-fs (sda5): 37 orphan inodes deleted
[    6.659711] EXT4-fs (sda5): recovery complete
[    6.885475] EXT4-fs (sda5): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
[   13.812093] udev[461]: starting version 163
[   13.840692] Adding 9854972k swap on /dev/sda7.  Priority:-1 extents:1 across:9854972k 
[   13.900874] intel ips 0000:00:1f.6: Warning: CPU TDP doesn't match expected value (found 25, expected 35)
[   13.900898] intel ips 0000:00:1f.6: PCI INT D -> GSI 19 (level, low) -> IRQ 19
[   13.901069] intel ips 0000:00:1f.6: failed to get i915 symbols, graphics turbo disabled
[   13.904358] Linux video capture interface: v2.00
[   13.914162] lp: driver loaded but no devices found
[   13.914542] cfg80211: Calling CRDA to update world regulatory domain
[   13.916635] uvcvideo: Found UVC 1.00 device Integrated Camera (17ef:480f)
[   13.920743] input: Integrated Camera as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.6/1-1.6:1.0/input/input4
[   13.920852] usbcore: registered new interface driver uvcvideo
[   13.920855] USB Video Class driver (v0.1.0)
[   13.934341] xhci_hcd 0000:0f:00.0: PCI INT A -> GSI 18 (level, low) -> IRQ 18
[   13.934395] xhci_hcd 0000:0f:00.0: setting latency timer to 64
[   13.934400] xhci_hcd 0000:0f:00.0: xHCI Host Controller
[   13.934509] xhci_hcd 0000:0f:00.0: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 3
[   13.934764] xhci_hcd 0000:0f:00.0: irq 18, io mem 0xf2200000
[   13.938019] usb usb3: No SuperSpeed endpoint companion for config 1  interface 0 altsetting 0 ep 129: using minimum values
[   13.938209] xHCI xhci_add_endpoint called for root hub
[   13.938212] xHCI xhci_check_bandwidth called for root hub
[   13.938247] hub 3-0:1.0: USB hub found
[   13.938253] hub 3-0:1.0: 4 ports detected
[   13.955469] intel ips 0000:00:1f.6: IPS driver initialized, MCP temp limit 65535
[   13.960616] type=1400 audit(1319873044.396:2): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" name="/sbin/dhclient3" pid=713 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   13.961099] type=1400 audit(1319873044.396:3): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" name="/usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-dhcp-client.action" pid=713 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   13.961467] type=1400 audit(1319873044.396:4): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" name="/usr/lib/connman/scripts/dhclient-script" pid=713 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   14.000645] Non-volatile memory driver v1.3
[   14.007837] cfg80211: World regulatory domain updated:
[   14.007840]     (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth), (max_antenna_gain, max_eirp)
[   14.007843]     (2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[   14.007845]     (2457000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @ 20000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[   14.007847]     (2474000 KHz - 2494000 KHz @ 20000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[   14.007849]     (5170000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[   14.007852]     (5735000 KHz - 5835000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[   14.015075] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.15
[   14.015099] NET: Registered protocol family 31
[   14.015100] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[   14.015103] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[   14.021833] acpi device:03: registered as cooling_device4
[   14.022436] input: Video Bus as /devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0A08:00/device:02/LNXVIDEO:00/input/input5
[   14.022550] ACPI: Video Device [VID] (multi-head: yes  rom: no  post: no)
[   14.026410] Bluetooth: Generic Bluetooth USB driver ver 0.6
[   14.026586] usbcore: registered new interface driver btusb
[   14.028606] tpm_tis 00:0b: 1.2 TPM (device-id 0x0, rev-id 78)
[   14.088604] iwlagn: Intel(R) Wireless WiFi Link AGN driver for Linux, in-tree:
[   14.088607] iwlagn: Copyright(c) 2003-2010 Intel Corporation
[   14.088669] iwlagn 0000:03:00.0: PCI INT A -> GSI 17 (level, low) -> IRQ 17
[   14.088677] iwlagn 0000:03:00.0: setting latency timer to 64
[   14.088733] iwlagn 0000:03:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Centrino(R) Ultimate-N 6300 AGN, REV=0x74
[   14.098038] iwlagn 0000:03:00.0: Tunable channels: 13 802.11bg, 24 802.11a channels
[   14.098147]   alloc irq_desc for 49 on node -1
[   14.098149]   alloc kstat_irqs on node -1
[   14.098201] iwlagn 0000:03:00.0: irq 49 for MSI/MSI-X
[   14.117713] thinkpad_acpi: ThinkPad ACPI Extras v0.24
[   14.117717] thinkpad_acpi: http://ibm-acpi.sf.net/
[   14.117719] thinkpad_acpi: ThinkPad BIOS 6LET66WW (1.31 ), EC 6MHT38WW-1.13
[   14.117722] thinkpad_acpi: Lenovo ThinkPad W510, model 43195RU
[   14.118787] thinkpad_acpi: detected a 8-level brightness capable ThinkPad
[   14.119092] thinkpad_acpi: radio switch found; radios are enabled
[   14.119295] HDA Intel 0000:00:1b.0: PCI INT B -> GSI 17 (level, low) -> IRQ 17
[   14.119418]   alloc irq_desc for 50 on node -1
[   14.119421]   alloc kstat_irqs on node -1
[   14.119437] HDA Intel 0000:00:1b.0: irq 50 for MSI/MSI-X
[   14.119648] HDA Intel 0000:00:1b.0: setting latency timer to 64
[   14.123893] thinkpad_acpi: rfkill switch tpacpi_bluetooth_sw: radio is unblocked
[   14.124506] iwlagn 0000:03:00.0: loaded firmware version 9.221.4.1 build 25532
[   14.124691] Registered led device: tpacpi::thinklight
[   14.124757] Registered led device: tpacpi::power
[   14.124773] Registered led device: tpacpi::standby
[   14.124797] Registered led device: tpacpi::thinkvantage
[   14.129554] thinkpad_acpi: Console audio control enabled, mode: monitor (read only)
[   14.132655] input: ThinkPad Extra Buttons as /devices/platform/thinkpad_acpi/input/input6
[   14.135704] phy0: Selected rate control algorithm 'iwl-agn-rs'
[   14.232488] HDA Intel 0000:01:00.1: PCI INT A -> GSI 16 (level, low) -> IRQ 16
[   14.232492] hda_intel: Disable MSI for Nvidia chipset
[   14.232562] HDA Intel 0000:01:00.1: setting latency timer to 64
[   14.298673] nvidia: module license 'NVIDIA' taints kernel.
[   14.298677] Disabling lock debugging due to kernel taint
[   14.369097] EXT4-fs (sda5): re-mounted. Opts: errors=remount-ro
[   14.767385] Synaptics Touchpad, model: 1, fw: 7.2, id: 0x1c0b1, caps: 0xd047b1/0xb40000/0xa0000
[   14.767390] Synaptics: Clickpad mode enabled
[   14.767395] serio: Synaptics pass-through port at isa0060/serio1/input0
[   14.821060] input: SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad as /devices/platform/i8042/serio1/input/input7
[   14.836294] type=1400 audit(1319873045.266:5): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" name="/usr/share/gdm/guest-session/Xsession" pid=1046 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   14.836325] type=1400 audit(1319873045.266:6): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" name="/sbin/dhclient3" pid=1047 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   14.836818] type=1400 audit(1319873045.276:7): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" name="/usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-dhcp-client.action" pid=1047 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   14.837100] type=1400 audit(1319873045.276:8): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" name="/usr/lib/connman/scripts/dhclient-script" pid=1047 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   14.837391] type=1400 audit(1319873045.276:9): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" name="/usr/lib/cups/backend/cups-pdf" pid=1050 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   14.837595] type=1400 audit(1319873045.276:10): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" name="/usr/sbin/tcpdump" pid=1051 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   14.838060] type=1400 audit(1319873045.276:11): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" name="/usr/bin/evince" pid=1048 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   15.341206] Bluetooth: L2CAP ver 2.14
[   15.341209] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[   15.346444] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[   15.346447] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[   15.349839] Bluetooth: SCO (Voice Link) ver 0.6
[   15.349841] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[   15.392224] e1000e 0000:00:19.0: irq 47 for MSI/MSI-X
[   15.412427] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[   15.412433] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[   15.412435] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
[   15.451953] e1000e 0000:00:19.0: irq 47 for MSI/MSI-X
[       15.452602] ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
```

`uname -r`:

```
2.6.35-22-generic
```

Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: If the caps-lock is blinking but you are able to login I do not think that actually is a panic.  Normally when things are so bad that we get a flashing caps-lock the computer will not respond.  I also note that if this dmesg is post such an event there is no panic in the dmesg.